# UWP IoT Core RTSP Streaming Audio

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, rtsp, windows-10-iot-core

I have managed to establish TCP host/clients sockets between multiple Raspberry Pi3. I would like to find out how to stream audio via RTSP among the host and clients. I have seen a lot of video streaming discussion but I haven't run into any audio streaming thread which I could reference. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, mylim. In your scenario, is the audio stream live stream? And are the Raspberry Pi devices used as RTSP client? I think you can try to use [Sharp RTSP](https://github.com/ngraziano/SharpRTSP) or any other RTSP library which is supported on Windows IoT Core to connect the client to the server.

Comment: In UWP, Media Element supports RTSP protocol, but please note the Supported audio and video formats on Windows IoT Core. Please refer to this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh986969(v=win.10)).

Comment: hi @MichaelXu-MSFT I am intending to stream live audio from a USB microphone audio adapter  for a start... also to stream audio media.

Comment: You can implement the RTSP protocol yourself, or use some library which supports in UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTSP is a realtime streaming protocol. It means that you can stream whatever you want in real time, such as video, audio, text and so on. RTP is a transport protocol which is used to transport media data which is negotiated over RTSP. So we can say RTSP is over RTP. The library SharpRSTP which is mentioned in my comment, supports in UWP. If you want stream audio only, you can use the G711Payload. G711 is a general audio encoder.Of course, you can find some other library from network. You can refer to the [RTSPClient.cs](https://github.com/ngraziano/SharpRTSP/blob/52f03b8203f4e06d9a39f301552065b1333e9e57/RtspClientExample/RTSPClient.cs) sample in the repo.

You can search a sample(titile is TCP Audio Streamer and Player (Voice Chat over IP)), it works fine.This is a proprietary VoIP project to send and receive audio data by TCP. You can move the client to UWP.

Comment: Thank Micheal. I will check it out.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT ... I have been exploring RTSP (https://github.com/ngraziano/SharpRTSP) and when I add RTSP into my IoT Core project, an error prompted stating 'NU-1202: Package Not Compatible'. Does that mean RTSP is not supported in IoT Core?